# Retrieving Client/Project MySql data on one page

Tags: php, mysql

This might be a lot, but hopefully I can get everything across correctly.

I purchased this time tracker: http://codecanyon.net/item/the-simple-clientproject-tracker/48930

What I am trying to do is list all clients with their associated projects all on one page.  As it was built, you can only view them separately in the sidebar as individual lists, or when you click on a client you will see that individual client's projects.  However a master list with all clients with all projects would be better, which is what I'm trying to achieve on a single page.

---

It looks like there are 3 tables that communicate with each other, [ project, clients, project_clients ]

Project columns: [ project_id, name, unique_id ]

Clients columns: [ client_id, name ]

Project_clients columns: [ project_id, client_id ]

---

Here are the existing functions:

```
/*
This returns the list of clients that are created with a link to view a list of their projects
*/
function getClientList(){
global $db,$secret;
$return = '';

$return = '<ul class="client_list">';

$query = "SELECT * FROM clients";
$res = $db->query($query,'assoc');

if(!empty($res)){
foreach($res as $row):

$return .= '<li><a href="client.php?client='.$row['client_id'].'" class="clientname" title="This client has '.tot_projects($row['client_id']).' projects associated to them">'.stripslashes($row['name']).'</a></li>';

endforeach;

}else{
$return .= '<li>No Clients Yet</li>';
}
$return .= '</ul>';
return $return;
}
```

--

```
/*
This will grab the each time a track was created and display it
@param MD5 $unique_id
*/

function getClientProjectTable($client_id){
global $db;
$clientLog = '';

//Get project_id
$query = "SELECT client_id FROM clients WHERE client_id = ".$db->prep($client_id);
$res = $db->query($query,'assoc');


$query = "SELECT project_id FROM project_clients WHERE client_id =".$db->prep($res[0]['client_id'])." ";
$resT = $db->query($query,'assoc');

//set vars
$thead = '<table id="timeLog" colspacing="0" colpadding="0" border="0">';
$thead .= '<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Hours</th><th></th></tr>
<tbody>';
$count_row = 0;
$alt = '';
$date = '';
$prevDate = '';
if($resT != false){
foreach($resT as $row):
$alt = ($count_row%2 == 0) ?'odd': '';

//Grab each track and process how much time has passed for it
$query = "SELECT name,unique_id FROM project WHERE project_id = ".$db->prep($row['project_id']);
$resProject = $db->query($query,'assoc');

$actions = '<a href="invoicebook.php?project_id='.urlencode($resProject[0]['unique_id']).'"><img src="images/invoice.png" alt="Invoice" style="vertical-align:middle;"/></a>';

//setup any actions to the row
$actions .= '<form name="projectDeleteAssign" action="process.php" method="post" style="display:inline; margin:0;" onsubmit="return confirmClientDelete();">
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenProjectID" value="'.$row['project_id'].'"  />
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenClientID" value="'.$res[0]['client_id'].'"  />
<input type="hidden" name="confirmDeleted" value="true"  />
<input type="submit" name="action" class="delete" value="Delete Assignment"  />
</form>';

//Check and see if you should check time based on if track has ended or is still running
$clientLog .= '<tr class="'.$alt.'"><td><a href="index.php?track='.urlencode($resProject[0]['unique_id']).'">'.stripslashes($resProject[0]['name']).'</a></td><td>'.tot_time($resProject[0]['unique_id'],'hours').'</td><td>'.$actions.'</td></tr>';

$count_row++;
endforeach;

}else{
$clientLog .= '<tr><td colspan="3">No Projects added to this client yet.</td></tr>';
}
$tfoot = '</tbody></table>';

return $thead.$clientLog.$tfoot;
}
```

--

```
/*
This returns the list of projects that are created with a link to view a detail view of each
*/
function getProjectList(){
global $db,$secret;
$return = '';

$return = '<ul>';

$query = "SELECT * FROM project";
$res = $db->query($query,'assoc');

if(!empty($res)){
foreach($res as $row):
$u_id = md5(utf8_encode($row['project_id'].$secret));

$return .= '<li><a href="index.php?track='.$u_id.'" class="'.bResult($row['startStop_track'],'timeStart','time').'">'.stripslashes($row['name']).'</a></li>';

endforeach;
}else{
$return .= '<li>No Projects Yet</li>';
}

$return .= '</ul>';

return $return;
}
```

--

```
/**
* 
* This will return the total number of projects
*/
function tot_projects($client = null){
global $db;

if($client){
$query = "SELECT count(p.project_id) FROM project p INNER JOIN project_clients pc ON pc.project_id = p.project_id WHERE client_id = ".$db->prep($client);
}else{
$query = "SELECT count(project_id) FROM project";
}
$res = $db->query($query,'row');

return $res[0][0];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So what have you written so far? What is the problem you're having?

Comment: I tried putting getClientProjectTable() into the foreach loop of getClientList() to see if that would work, but no.  I'm not too familiar with retrieving database info, so I'm pretty lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your getClientList function with this:

```
function getClientList2(){
    global $db,$secret;

    $return = "";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM clients";
    $res = $db->query($query,'assoc');

    if(!empty($res)){
        foreach($res as $row) {
            $return .= getClientProjectTable($row['client_id']);
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

I've stripped out a lot of the formatting, but you can add that back in again if it works.

Comment: didn't work out.  I feel it might be something like this function that's included in the file:
`/**** This will return the total number of projects */
function tot_projects($client = null){
global $db;

if($client){
 $query = "SELECT count(p.project_id) FROM project p INNER JOIN project_clients pc ON pc.project_id = p.project_id WHERE client_id = ".$db->prep($client);
}else{
 $query = "SELECT count(project_id) FROM project";
}
$res = $db->query($query,'row');

return $res[0][0];
}`

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work? Did it produce errors, print the wrong information, or something else?

Comment: It produced a html table with no data.

Comment: It looks like your `getClientList` function gets a list of clients; and `getClientProjectTable`takes a clientID and lists all their projects. Try adding some debugging into both functions, to make sure that they're being called, and that `getClientProjectTable` is indeed getting a clientID when it's called.

Comment: It appears to be working now for some reason.  I'll do some more testing before I know for sure.